# Getting ID3 tags from Streaming URL

Tags: android, stream, mp3, dropbox-api

I am trying to make a Stream Music player application that you can play the mp3s from your dropbox account on stream. But DropboxAPI doesnt give you ID3 information as metadata . So i need to find a way to get the ID3 informations like artist and song name so i can list the files on the screen.

I tried MediaMetadataRetriever class , but it always gave Illegel argument exception for URI, and i tried also different URLs from different websites ,still result is the same.

So can you suggest an alternative way to get the ID3 tags of a Mp3 file from a stream URL.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/

Comment: But it doesnt define a way of how to use Mp3 url links. It takes "File" as an argument and file is for local storage only, i dont want to download the whole mp3 to my local storage